# Understanding java ByteBuffer

Tags: java, bytebuffer

I have been trying to understand how Java ByteBuffer works. My aim is to write a **string** to **ByteBuffer** and read it back. I want to understand how `ByteBuffer` properties like `Limit, Capacity, Remaining, Position` gets affected due to read/write operations.

Below is my test program (removed import statements for brevity).

```
public class TestBuffer {

private ByteBuffer bytes;
private String testStr = "Stackoverflow is a great place to discuss tech stuff!";

public TestBuffer() {
    bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(1000);
    System.out.println("init: " + printBuffer());
}

public static void main(String a[]) {
    TestBuffer buf = new TestBuffer();
    try {
        buf.writeBuffer();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    buf.readBuffer();
}

// write testStr to buffer
private void writeBuffer() throws IOException {
    byte[] b = testStr.getBytes();
    BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(b));
    in.read(bytes.array());
    in.close();
    System.out.println("write: " + printBuffer());
}

// read buffer data back to byte array and print
private void readBuffer() {
    bytes.flip();
    byte[] b = new byte[bytes.position()];
    bytes.position(0);
    bytes.get(b);
    System.out.println("data read: " + new String(b));
    System.out.println("read: " + printBuffer());
}

public String printBuffer() {
    return "ByteBuffer [limit=" + bytes.limit() + ", capacity=" + bytes.capacity() + ", position="
            + bytes.position() + ", remaining=" + bytes.remaining() + "]";
}
```

}

**Output**

```
init: ByteBuffer [limit=1000, capacity=1000, position=0, remaining=1000]
write: ByteBuffer [limit=1000, capacity=1000, position=0, remaining=1000]
data read: 
read: ByteBuffer [limit=0, capacity=1000, position=0, remaining=0]
```

As you can see, there is no data after calling `readBuffer()` and no change in value if various fields after write and read operations.

**Update**

Below is the working piece of code from [Android Screen Library](https://github.com/iyouq/android-screenshot-library/blob/master/demo/src/pl/polidea/asl/ScreenshotService.java) which I was originally trying to understand

```
// retrieve the screenshot
            // (this method - via ByteBuffer - seems to be the fastest)
            ByteBuffer bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate (ss.width * ss.height * ss.bpp / 8);
            is = new BufferedInputStream(is);   // buffering is very important apparently
            is.read(bytes.array());             // reading all at once for speed
            bytes.position(0);                  // reset position to the beginning of ByteBuffer
```

Please help me to understand this.

Thanks

---

Comment: You should never ignore the return value of `in.read(byte[])`. You may not retrieve all the bytes you are asking for. The byte array buffer given may not be completely filled (as you may reach end of stream before that, or the stream may have other reasons to give a partial message in response).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your buffer is never filled. `bytes.array()` simply retrieves the backing byte array. If you write anything to this then the `ByteBuffer` fields - except the array itself of course - are unaffected. So the position stays at zero.

What you are doing in `in.read(bytes.array())` is identical to `byte[] tmp = bytes.array()` followed by `in.read(tmp)`. Changes to the `tmp` variable cannot be reflected in the `bytes` instance. The backing array is changed which may mean that the contents of the `ByteBuffer` is changed as well. But the offsets into the backing byte array - including the *position* and *limit* - aren't.

You should only fill the `ByteBuffer` using any of the `put` methods (that do not take an index) such as [`put(byte[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#put-byte:A-).

---

I'll provide a code fragment that may get you thinking on how to handle strings, encodings and character and byte buffers:

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.CharBuffer;
import java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder;
import java.nio.charset.CoderResult;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class TestBuffer {

    private static final String testStr = "Stackoverflow is a great place to discuss tech stuff!";
    private static final boolean END_OF_INPUT = true;

    private ByteBuffer bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(1000);

    public TestBuffer() {

        System.out.println("init   : " + bytes.toString());
    }

    public static void main(String a[]) {
        TestBuffer buf = new TestBuffer();
        buf.writeBuffer();
        buf.readBuffer();
    }

    // write testStr to buffer
    private void writeBuffer() {
        CharBuffer testBuffer = CharBuffer.wrap(testStr);
        CharsetEncoder utf8Encoder = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.newEncoder();
        CoderResult result = utf8Encoder.encode(testBuffer, bytes, END_OF_INPUT);
        if (result.isError()) {
            bytes.clear();
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("That didn't go right because " + result.toString());
        }
        if (result.isOverflow()) {
            bytes.clear();
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Well, too little buffer space.");
        }
        System.out.println("written: " + bytes.toString());
        bytes.flip();
    }

    // read buffer data back to byte array and print
    private void readBuffer() {
        byte[] b = new byte[bytes.remaining()];
        bytes.get(b);
        System.out.println("data   : " + new String(b, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        System.out.println("read   : " + bytes.toString());
        bytes.clear();
    }
}
```

Note that buffers and streams are really two separate ways of handling sequential data. If you are trying to use both of them at the same time you may be trying to be *too* clever.

You could also solve this without `CharBuffer` and `ByteBuffer` using a `byte[]` buffer and a [`StringReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/StringReader.html) wrapped by a [`ReaderInputStream`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/ReaderInputStream.html).

---

That Android piece of code completely abuses the `ByteBuffer`. It should just have created a `byte[]` and wrapped that, setting the *limit* to the *capacity*. Whatever you do, ***do not use it as an example on `ByteBuffer` handling***. It made my eyes water in disgust. Code like that is a bug waiting to happen.

Comment: Shouldn't `in.read(bytes.array())` read into ByteBuffer? Here `bytes` refers to ByteBuffer.

Comment: No, it doesn't. It only fills the backing array, but the `ByteBuffer` instance doesn't (cannot) get notified of this. In other words, the *contents* of the ByteBuffer are changed, but neither of the offsets including the position and limit is. This is the same as `byte[] tmp = bytes.array()` followed by `in.read(tmp)`.

Comment: Integrated this into the answer, and gave an example that completely rewrote the `writeBuffer` method without streams. It gives a clue how you can use buffers without requiring a buffer of the same size as the string. It doesn't require streams although an alternative would be using an `InputStreamReader` instead of the `CharBuffer` and `ByteBuffer`.

Comment: thanks for elaborate answer. I have a working piece of Android  code (but didn't want to include that) which works that way. I have updated the question with snippet.

Comment: And I've added some abuse at the end of my answer in response to that :)

Answer (score 1):

You are not writting anything in the `writeBuffer()` method.

You may use something like `bytes.put(b)`.

Comment: I think line `in.read(bytes.array());` should read the data to ByteBuffer

Answer (score 1):

Although this question has been answered long time ago, let me also supplement some info. here.

There are 2 problems in the `writeBuffer()` and `readBuffer()` method separately which leads you failed to get your expected result.

### 1) **`writeBuffer()` method**

As explained by Maarten Bodewes above regarding the nature of bytebuffer's array, you cannot use `byteBuffer.array()` directly for reading from a Stream in your

Alternatively, if you want to keep testing the relationship between *InputStream* and *ByteBuffer* as your sample (which is also a common practice on server side application for handling incoming messages), you would require an additional byte array.

### 2) `readBuffer()` method

The original code is good of using an extra byte array for retrieving the context in bytebuffer for printing it.

However, the problem here is the improper use of `flip()` and `position()` method.

1. The `flip()` method should only be called right before you want to change the **state** of the bytebuffer from `storing context` to `exporting context`. So this method here should appear right before the line of `bytes.get(b);` instead. In the provided sample, it was too early to call this method before the line `byte[] b = new byte[bytes.position()];` , as `flip()` method would change the **position** flag of the bytebuffer to 0 while setting the **limit** flag to current position.
2. There are no points of setting the bytebuffer's position to 0 explicitly in the sample codes. In case you want to keep storing context to the bytebuffer again at some later time by starting from current position (i.e. without overwriting existing context in it), you should follow this workflow:

   2.1  store bytebuffer's current position: *i.e. `int pos = bytebuffer.position();`*
   2.2  process with the bytebuffer which may affect the position flag of it: *e.g. `bytebuffer.get(byte[] dst)` etc.*
   2.3  restore bytebuffer's position flag to original value: *i.e. `bytebuffer.position(pos);`*

---

Here I have slightly modified your sample code for achieving what you want to do:

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

public class TestBuffer {

    private ByteBuffer bytes;
    private String testStr = "Stackoverflow is a great place to discuss tech stuff!";

    public TestBuffer() {
        bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(1000);
        System.out.println("init: " + printBuffer());
    }

    public static void main(String a[]) {
        TestBuffer buf = new TestBuffer();
        try {
            buf.writeBuffer();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        buf.readBuffer();
    }

    // write testStr to buffer
    private void writeBuffer() throws IOException {
        byte[] b = testStr.getBytes();
        BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(b));
        // in.read(bytes.array());
        byte[] dst = new byte[b.length];
        in.read(dst);
        bytes.put(dst);
        in.close();
        System.out.println("write: " + printBuffer());
    }

    // read buffer data back to byte array and print
    private void readBuffer() {
        //bytes.flip();
        byte[] b = new byte[bytes.position()];
        //bytes.position(0);
        int pos = bytes.position();
        bytes.flip();   // bytes.rewind(); could achieve the same result here, use which one depends on whether:
                        // (1) reading to this bytebuffer is finished and fine to overwrite the current context in this bytebuffer afterwards: can use flip(); or 
                        // (2) just want to tentatively traverse this bytebuffer from the begining to current position, 
                        //      and keep writing to this bytebuffer again later from current position.      
        bytes.get(b);
        bytes.position(pos);
        System.out.println("data read: " + new String(b));
        System.out.println("read: " + printBuffer());
    }

    public String printBuffer() {
        return "ByteBuffer [limit=" + bytes.limit() + ", capacity=" + bytes.capacity() + ", position="
                + bytes.position() + ", remaining=" + bytes.remaining() + "]";
    }

}
```